# Untenable rendering times (12+hrs) on simple 3D objects

Tags: adobe-photoshop, 3d

I just upgraded to CC, and I haven't really done any 3D modeling before so any advice would be greatly appreciated. I made three fairly small objects: a table, a glass, and a beer bottle, as well as an image used as a postcard object background. None of these shapes seem particularly complex, so I'm wondering why it has to render for 12+ hours (!!). What I'm thinking may be the problem is that the materials and opacity layers that I'm using for the bottle are equivalent to A6 at 300 dpi. I wanted to avoid any pixelation on the label I created for the bottle, but did I give it too much to think about? I'm using a brand new MacBook Pro, so RAM and processing power shouldn't be the issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well have you looked at how much ram your consuming. Most likely your just simply blowing your memory so the system has to page. Thered no info here so the question is totally unanswerable.

Answer (score 1):

A new MacBook Pro should have 16 GB of RAM fitted but depending on the Graphics settings you could be using a chunk of that for display memory and you might have other processes running which are consuming more RAM and processing power.  The other question is how many vertexes are in your model, a glass and bottle are likely to be excessively smoothed, (it is always tempting to go to too high a level of detail), if so you could be consuming most of your RAM with just your model.

I would suggest a couple of steps:

1. Make sure ***Nothing*** else is running on your machine.
2. Try rendering each of your objects in turn and timing each to see if one of them is the problem.
3. Try lowering the level of detail in each item, especially the glass and bottle - you may be surprised at how crude a model can produce acceptable results.
4. I would also suggest trying exporting your current model and importing into [Blender](https://www.blender.org/) to see if CC is the problem, (it is free so no cost issues).